# Insert data into sqlite3 database with API

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-requests, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data from a web API into my database (I am using sqlite3 on python 3.7.2) and I can't find any tutorials on how do to so. So far all my code is:

```
import requests, sqlite3
database = sqlite3.connect("ProjectDatabase.db")
cur = database.cursor()

d = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2019/drivers")
```

I'm aiming to get the names and driver numbers of each driver and insert them all into a table called Drivers. (I'm also using more APIs with more tables, but if I figure out how to do one then the rest should be fine.) I assume I have to do something like

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Drivers VALUES(?,?), (driverName, driverNumber)
''')
```

but I'm struggling to figure out how to insert the data straight into the table from the website. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary to parse the XML output? This particular API supports JSON response.

Comment: Try to just get the names from the website without putting them in a database first.

Comment: You correctly assume. The normal way has 3 steps: 1/ get the data 2/ parse the data 3/ insert the relevant parts into the database.

Comment: I don't quite see where you struggle to be honest. It basically goes  as follow: `request -> parse -> insert` at what point do you struggle?

Comment: @LukaszSalitra I don't know, I used the 'requests.get()' and that's what it automatically gave me. If JSON is needed then that's fine, I'd just need to figure out how to get the JSON response instead of XML.

Comment: @576i I could but if I were to enter them all manually then that's time consuming, and it's the simplest API I'm using so I want to figure out how to do it with something simple

Comment: @Grace the `requests` just sends a plain HTTP request. It can either request everything you want it to request. It's defined in the header. Change the url to `http://ergast.com/api/f1/2019/drivers.json` parse the json proceed as usual.

Comment: @Vulpex thanks - the bit I'm struggling with is the `parse` section, I've never had to do anything like this before and I've never worked with json before either

Comment: If you want to parse the HTML version, BeautifulSoup will help. But json is more compact and easier to parse...

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks - I think from the comments I'll use json, even though I've never worked with it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment section in the OP, the problem seemed to be how to parse the API point.

```
d = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2019/drivers.json")
d = d.json()
drivers = d["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"]
```

would be the answer to that question to access all drivers provided by that API.

To add the entries to the db you can use the following:

```
for dr in drivers:
    name = dr["familyName"]
    number = dr["permanentNumber"]
    sql = 'INSERT INTO Drivers (name,number) VALUES(?,?)'
    val = (name,number)
    cur.execute(sql,val)
```

with this solution you don't have to use specify the index and can directly access the parameter you're interested in.

Comment: I've edited the loop into the answer. You can basically take that answer as posted and put it into your code, shouldn't need too much editing, except ofcourse the db connection and cursor creation.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to use this but it's throwing up an error saying there's no such column "name" (it doesn't with "driverName" either [same with "number"]) - I tried to specify the columns I'm entering the data into but it still throws up this error.

Comment: @Grace have you changed the url and added the `drivers = d["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"]` part? It should work given you've copied the complete answer.

Comment: I have, I've just double checked and it's the same as yours.

Comment: @Grace yeah I just saw I've goofed with the sql statement, this way it should work and the way I usually do it. note: in the sql statement I name the columns I want to add, in my test db the column names were name and number.

Comment: if the sql statement was like `cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Drivers(driverName, driverNumber) VALUES(?,?), (name, number)''')` would it work? I've tried it this way and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: No because the statement is wrong. it should be `cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Drivers VALUES(?,?)''', (name, number))` you're setting the quotation marks at the wrong place. That was my mistake in the answer.

Comment: @Grace do you commit? you need to write `database .commit()` after you've inserted all your data.

Comment: yeah I just double checked and figured that was the reason why. fixed now, thanks :)