# Store data from get API into Database using Python 3

Tags: python, sqlite, api

I've seen an example on how to store data coming from get API to sqlite db from the following link [Insert data into sqlite3 database with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258575/insert-data-into-sqlite3-database-with-api).
However, I couldn't understand this part of the code:

```
drivers = d["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"]
```

Can someone please show me how we can store data from APi as shown in the shared link or at least clarification of that line of the code which I didn't understand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nesting in the d json object. so the above example is accessing the json like this:

```
d =  { 
    "MrData":{
         "DriverTable":{
             "Drivers":{
                 "familyName": "albert",
                 "permanentNumber": 200
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I hope this illustrates what is going on

Comment: @Joe does this clarify your confusion

Comment: Thanks Night King. In this case, the Drivers is the name of the table, so what about MrData and DriverTable? what should I replace ["MRData"]["DriverTable"] with? Thanks

Comment: if you go to this link http://ergast.com/api/f1/2019/drivers.json

Comment: can i see your own json file @Joe

Comment: Can't share the whole api response  but this is a snap for it: {'data': {'name': 'edward', 'description': 'my description','date': '01-01-2020','id': 'myStringID'}}

Comment: @Joe if this is the beginning then your needle in the haystack is "data". so it would be "data" replacing "MRData"

Comment: @Joe do you now understand?